# Filter and merge a dataframe in Python using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I need to filter out who is the owner of which books so we can send them notifications. I am having trouble merging the data in the format I need.

Existing dataframe

| Book | Owner |
| --- | --- |
| The Alchemist | marry |
| To Kill a Mockingbird | john |
| Lord of the Flies | abel |
| Catcher in the Ry | marry |
| Alabama | julia;marry |
| Invisible Man | john |

I need to create new dataframe that lists the owners in column A and all the books they own in Column B.
Desired output

| Owners | Books |
| --- | --- |
| marry | The Alchemist, Catcher in the Ry, Alabama |
| john | To Kill a Mockingbird, Invisible Man |
| abel | Lord of the Flies |
| julia | Alabama |

I tried creating 2 dfs from and then merging but the results are never accurate. Anyone know a more efficient way to do this?

Current code not working:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd 

file1 = Path.cwd() / "./bookgrid.xlsx"


df1 = pd.read_excel(file1)
df2 = pd.read_excel(file1)

##Perfrom the Vlookup Merge
merge = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="left")

merge.to_excel("./results.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
(df.assign(Owner=lambda d: d['Owner'].str.split(';'))
   .explode('Owner')
   .groupby('Owner', as_index=False, sort=False).agg(', '.join)
)
```

*NB. if you need the plural form in the column headers, add `.add_suffix('s')` or `.rename(columns={'Book': 'Books', 'Owner': 'Owners'})`.*

Output:

```
   Owner                                       Book
0  marry  The Alchemist, Catcher in the Ry, Alabama
1   john       To Kill a Mockingbird, Invisible Man
2   abel                          Lord of the Flies
3  julia                                    Alabama
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets try something new

```
s = df['Owner'].str.get_dummies(';')
(s.T @ df['Book'].add(', ')).str.rstrip(', ')
```

Result

```
abel                             Lord of the Flies
john          To Kill a Mockingbird, Invisible Man
julia                                      Alabama
marry    The Alchemist, Catcher in the Ry, Alabama
dtype: object
```

Comment: Better use `removesuffix` (or `str[:-2]`) not `rstrip`, while this works here, this can have sides effects when generalizing ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not the fastest way, but  here's an easy to follow way.

```
import pandas as pd 

# Set up the example dataframe
data = {'Book':['The Alchemist','To Kill a Mockingbird','Lord of the Flies','Catcher in the Ry','Alabama','Invisible Man'],'Owner':['marry','john','abel','marry','julia;marry','john']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Turn your string of names into a list of names
df2['Owner'] = df2['Owner'].apply(lambda x: x.split(";"))

# get a unique list of customers
unique_owners = {single_owner for owners_list in df2['Owner'] for single_owner in owners_list}
# Gives a set -> {'abel', 'john', 'julia', 'marry'}

# for each customer, slice the dataframe for each customer
df2[['marry' in row for row in df2['Owner']]]

# select only the books, not the names
df2[['marry' in row for row in df2['Owner']]]['Book']

# convert the books to a list. Alternative - ",".join(df2[['marry' in row for row in df2['Owner']]]['Book']) turns all the books into a single piece of text.
df2[['marry' in row for row in df2['Owner']]]['Book'].to_list()

# set up data storage
names = []
books = []

# iterate through he unique owners set
[(names.append(single_owner), books.append(df2[[single_owner in row for row in df2['Owner']]]['Book'].to_list())) for single_owner in unique_owners]

new_df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Owner':names,'Books':books})
new_df2
```